# How to reverse-proxy a Voila server with Apache?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, voila

The [Voila documentation](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html) explains only how to reverse-proxy the Voila server with `nginx`. For reasons beyond my control I need to use Apache instead, but I cannot find instructions on how to do so. I tried to modify a reverse-proxy setup I successfully used for proxying JupyterHub before, but to no avail.

I also read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69224610) but that didn't help much, because 1) the problem described there does not match my use case as it refers to Voila being used from JupyterHub as an extension, whereas I am interested in proxying Voila "on its own", and 2) there are no answers (yet)... :-)

Any help would be very much appreciated.